# Finding out what triggered a task run programmatically

Tags: airflow

Is there a way to programmatically determine what triggered the current task run of the PythonOperator from inside of the operator?

I want to differentiate between the task runs triggered on schedule, those catching up, and those triggered by the backfill CLI command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template context contains two variables: `dag_run` and `run_id` that you can use to determine whether the run was scheduled, a backfill, or externally triggered.

```
from airflow import jobs

def python_target(**context):
  is_backfill = context["dag_run"].is_backfill
  is_external = context["dag_run"].external_trigger
  is_latest = context["execution_date"] == context["dag"].latest_execution_date
  # More code...
```